# what set are these from

Tags: set-identification

Have some lego bags with 232g9 printed on them. What set would these be from? Thanks in advance
Cheers Curtis

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Bricks SE! The printed code on bags is meaningless when trying to find the set. Have a read of the answer above, and if that still doesn’t help, then please upload a photo of your bags